# Accessing my capture group in regex pattern matching in Expect to a variable

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, expect, capture-group

I can't get this to work and am not sure why.  I have a line that has spaces between numbers at the end of the line.  I need Expect to match this line and put the numbers and spaces into a capture group and I need to access that capture group later in my script.

A sample line is: this is a line 2 4 5 6

My expect -re statement: expect -re {^this\sis\sa\sline((\s\d)+$)}

I am then trying to access the capture group using $expect_out(1,string)

If I check http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ it says match group 1 is "2 4 5 6" so I'm pretty sure the pattern is matching right and I would expect to see "2 4 5 6" in $expect_out(1,string), right?

However, when I run my expect script, I am seeing:

```
expect: does " \u001b[Js\u001b[Jt\u001b[Jr\u001b[Je\u001b[Ja\u001b[Jm\u001b[Js\u001b[J\r\n\u001b[H\u001b[J\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\this is a line 2 4 5 6\r\n\r\nSelect which option you would    like to change\r\nusing the index number: " (spawn_id exp5) match regular expression "^this\sis\sa\sline((\s\d)+$)"? Gate "this?is?a?line*"? gate=yes re=no
expect: timed out
can't read "expect_out(1,string)": no such element in array
while executing
"set streams $expect_out(1,string)"
(file "check-config" line 35)
```

How can I get "2 4 5 6" (or " 2 4 5 6") into a variable to use later in my expect script?

Also, while I have your attention, what does `Gate=Yes re=No` mean?  I assume the re=No means the regex didn't match, but what's a `Gate` in Expect's world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are including line anchors <kbd>^</kbd> and <kbd>$</kbd> in your regex. The string you're trying to match is clearly a multi-line string, but Tcl's default matching treats newlines just like a regular character. Another complicating factor is that Tcl considers a newline to be `\n` but expect is using `\r\n` as the line terminator.

If you enable [newline sensitive matching](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M88) in the regular expression and take the carriage return into account, you may find this regular expression works: `(?n)^this\sis\sa\sline((?:\s\d)+)\r?$`

Testing:

```
$ expect <<END
spawn sh -c {echo foo; echo "this is a line 2 4 5 6"; echo bar}
exp_internal 1
expect -re {(?n)^this\sis\sa\sline((?:\s\d)+)\r?$}
END
```

```
spawn sh -c echo foo; echo "this is a line 2 4 5 6"; echo bar
Gate keeper glob pattern for '(?n)^this\sis\sa\sline((?:\s\d)+)\r?$' is 'this?is?a?line*'. Activating booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "(?n)^this\sis\sa\sline((?:\s\d)+)\r?$"? Gate "this?is?a?line*"? gate=no
foo

expect: does "foo\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "(?n)^this\sis\sa\sline((?:\s\d)+)\r?$"? Gate "this?is?a?line*"? gate=no
this is a line 2 4 5 6
bar

expect: does "foo\r\nthis is a line 2 4 5 6\r\nbar\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "(?n)^this\sis\sa\sline((?:\s\d)+)\r?$"? Gate "this?is?a?line*"? gate=yes re=yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "this is a line 2 4 5 6\r"
expect: set expect_out(1,string) " 2 4 5 6"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "foo\r\nthis is a line 2 4 5 6\r"
```

Comment: That worked perfectly for me.  Thanks!  What's a "Gate" in Expect?

Comment: I don't know about expect's "gate" -- it looks like it's trying to convert the regex into a glob pattern, but in this case that's not helpful at all, since you need the regex capturing parentheses.

Comment: And what's the (?n) at the beginning?

Comment: Follow the link I provided in the answer.

Comment: Got it.  Sorry for my oversight.  Thanks!